# Assigning unique ids to descendants of included layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layouts setup (I omitted the irrelevant tags):

```
main.xml:
<include
    android:id="@+id/test1"
    layout="@layout/mylayout"
    />

<include
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    layout="@layout/mylayout"
    />

mylayout.xml:
<LinearLayout
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myedittext"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that this particular example is *crucially* oversimplified, my actual `mylayout.xml` is complex and contains a lot of sublayouts and subviews with a lot of ids and I would *really* not like to inline it into `main.xml`.

So, I want to reuse the layout `mylayout.xml` multiple times. You might notice that the two EditTexts will have duplicate ids. This seemed not to be a problem since I only use `R.id.myedittext` on the activity initialization to find the views with the `test1` or `test2` layouts being roots for `findViewById`, and after that I access these EditTexts via the View objects directly. I find Butterknife very convenient for this, the code looks like that:

```
class LayoutHolder {
     @InjectView(R.id.myedittext)
     EditText editText;
     // ...
     static LayoutHolder create(View root) {
         LayoutHolder holder = new LayoutHolder();
         ButterKnife.inject(holder, root);
         return holder;
     }
}
```

The problems emerged when I tried to change the screen orientation: both EditTexts restored the same state due to these non-unique ids. Ok, I thought, I just have to define some ids in the `values` directory and then use the `View.setId` method on the EditTexts. There are some issues with this approach though: in particular, I will have to set these ids manually and programmatically for each and every view with an ID within `mylayout.xml`. What is more, even if I do that, I will not be able to access these subviews in some uniform way anymore since they will all have different IDs (in particular, I won't be able to do these nice Butterknife injections).

I've come up to some other ways of resolving this, but they are even more complex and ugly. So, is there some nice and generic way to accomplish my needs? I wonder I wasn't able to find anything on the web, because reusing layouts in order to avoid code duplication (xml duplication actually, but whatever) seems like quite a natural thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this code that I found in an open source project.

```
public class Utils {

    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
     /**
     * Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int}.
     * This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.
     *
     * @return a generated ID value
     */
    private static int generateViewId() {
        for (; ; ) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) {
                newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            }
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int generateId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

            return generateViewId();
        }
        else {

            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Patch around butterknife, so it will support two ids like this

```
@InjectView(R.id.mylayout, R.id.myedittext)
```